# Link to homepage still pointing to old site in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have migrated to a new host.

I have restored database but run a search and replace to the sql file before that to point to new ip.

also defined WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME to point to new ip.

My problem is the Home in the nav bar still pointing to old site the rest of the links are fine. just the home.

```
<div class="header-right">
<div class="nav-top">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="nav" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-1257" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1257">
                 <a href="(site1)">Home</a></li>
             <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-39 current_page_item menu-item-100">
                 <a href="(site2)">Our Story</a></li>
             <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-102">
                 <a href="(site2)">Services</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

First check that in menu you have set custom link/URL for `Home` page OR not.I think you have set custom link for the `Home` link. and this is your old site link.

Comment: In admin, `Appearance->Menu` Section there are box on left-hand-side near menu arrow, the box called `Links` is for custom links.

Comment: If it is custom link then in menu structure at the right-hand-side of `Home` link, there is a test like `custom`.